# How to fix weight painting for a glove?

Tags: rigging

I would like for the glove to stay put when I move the hand. I've been fighting with this for a while now trying all kinds of things with the weight paint. I have another version where I managed to do it (not perfectly, still moves a little) but I can't remember what I did. I tried copying the weights there but nothing. There's no actual hand under the glove by the way. I'm attaching the file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bscsabxsbsikmp/Captain%20Blender%203.blend?dl=0
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your troubles come from the fact that some gloves vertices weights are assigned to vertex groups unuseful (i.e. the thumb one): remove all assignements to unuseful vertex groups and assign some weight to the forearm bone only.